# How can I asymmetrically encrypt data using OpenPGP with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encryption, gnupg, encryption-asymmetric, openpgp

This feels like it should be dead simple, yet I'm not having any luck.

The scenario is this: I have a public *.asc key file. I want to use *this file* (not my personal keyring) to encrypt data on a server, so that I can decrypt it locally with a secret key.

From the command line I can achieve this using `gpg`, but I'd prefer to use a Ruby library that isn't just a wrapper around the CLI (i.e., presumably one that provides bindings to the C library). I've looked at the GPGME and OpenPGP gems and haven't been able to figure out how to use them. The documentation (especially for OpenPGP) is quite sparse.

Here, for example, is something I've tried using GPGME, without any luck:

```
key = GPGME::Data.new(File.open(path_to_file))
data = GPGME::Data.new("I want to encrypt this string.")

# Raises GPGME::Error::InvalidValue
GPGME::Ctx.new do |ctx|
  e = ctx.encrypt(key, data)
end
```

Has anyone been through this already? Surely this can't be that complicated?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GPGME, but does it work if you try `GPGME::Key.import(File.open(path_to_file))`? If it still fails, what if you Base64-decode the .asc and try again?

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you would do this from the command line?  Typical usage requires a recipients public key to be imported into the keyring first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* I've now got this figured out. It was actually just a few simple pieces I was missing:

1. Initializing the `GPGME::Ctx` object with a `keylist_mode` of `GPGME::KEYLIST_MODE_EXTERN`.
2. Importing the public key file using `GPGME::Ctx#import`.
3. Using `GPGME::Crypto#encrypt` to perform the encryption and specifying the correct recipient.

So my solution now looks like this:

```
key = GPGME::Data.new(File.open(path_to_file))
data = GPGME::Data.new("I want to encrypt this string.")

GPGME::Ctx.new(GPGME::KEYLIST_MODE_EXTERN) do |ctx|
  ctx.import(key)
  crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new(:armor => true, :always_trust => true)
  e = crypto.encrypt(data, :recipients => "recipient@domain.com")
end
```